# Обработка изображения с помощью преобразования Фурье

Tags: python

На вход поступает ихображение в формате RGB. Необходимо его обработать с помощью преобразования Фурье  используя библиотеку. Далее наименьшие значения коофицентов(например, <=5) обнуляются и происходит обратное преобразование. В результате мы должны выделить детали на изображении.

```
def fourier(img_rgb):

    plt.figure(figsize=(6.4*2, 1.8*2), constrained_layout=False)

    img_с1 = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img_c2 = np.fft.fft2(img_с1)
    # обрабатываем второе изображение. Берем [спектральный]коофицент, если он меньше нашего значения(например, 5), то зануляем(0). Выводим новое изображение. 
    img_c2[abs(img_c2) <= 0.5] = 0.0
    img_c4 = np.fft.ifft2(img_c2)
    img_c5 = img_с1 - img_c4

    plt.subplot(151), plt.imshow(img_с1, "gray"), plt.title("Original Image")
    plt.subplot(152), plt.imshow(np.log(1+np.abs(img_c2)), "gray"), plt.title("Spectrum")
    plt.subplot(153), plt.imshow(np.log(1+np.abs(img_c4)),"gray"), plt.title("Image after Fourier")
    plt.show()
```

Однако, получается, что на изображении выделяются помехи, а детали практически не видны.

Изображение Лена обработанное с помощью Фурье преобразования. Обнулены спектральные коофициенты, которые <= 5, сделано обратное преобразование и выделены детали изображения:
[image]

Правильно выполнено Фурье преобразование?

Comment: Вы занулили маленькие **по значению** коэффициенты. Если задача состояла в том, чтобы провести частотную фильтрацию, то нужно занулять коэффициенты в соответствующих местах фурье-образа. Например, для удаления мелких деталей оставляете только коэффициенты с малыми **индексами** (соответствуют низким частотам)

Comment: 1) Вы удаляете слишком много (половину яркости исходного изображения. 2) Вы используете качественное исходное изображение, на котором помех просто нет. Любая его фильтрация, субъективно, только ухудшит его качество.

Comment: @MBo вы действительно правы! Оказываетсяя необходимо оставлять только коэффициенты с малыми индексами. Вы можете подсказать, как именно найти малые индексы?

Comment: Например, в первом квадранте оставить те элементы, индексы которых x<n/4 и y<n/4, аналогично для других квадрантов - оставлять то что близко к углам

Comment: @MBo а нормально, что обратное преобразование фурье осветляем немного изображение?(Можно сравнить с 1 и 3 на прикрепленном изображении.
А также, подскажите пожалуйста, правильно ли я оставил элементы,  индексы которых x<n/4 и y<n/4, на [изображении](https://imgur.com/xJM10pZ)?

Comment: Вообще я бы ожидал затемнения за счёт того, что часть энергии спектра вырезана, но, может, возник какой сдвиг уровня - посмотреть нулевой коэффициент после Фурье исходного изображения и обработанного. Думаю, правильно, хоnя это более похоже на n/8. Дело в том ещё, что массив после Фурье может располагаться по-разному в зависимости от реализации, например, двумерное Фурье порой выводят для просмотра так, чтобы нулевой коэффициент был в центре, а не по углам (при этом картинка часто выглядит как светлый крест). Как у вас - не знаю.